# “A special interest” vs. “special interests”

Tags: articles, zero-article

I’m writing a short paragraph about myself. I find it hard to determine what article I should use in this following sentence:

1. I have ***a*** special interest in learning languages, computer programming, astronomy, and economy.
2. I have *special interest**s*** in learning languages, computer programming, astronomy, and economy.

Should I use ***a*** special interest in the singular with the article like in the first version, or should I use *special interest**s*** in the plural without the article since what comes after it is more than one thing?

Could you guys please help me out here and tell me how to handle this type of sentence?

Comment: As listed in OED and other dictionaries, "special interest" is a person or a group. You don't use it in your sentence. OED: "A group of people or an organization seeking or receiving special advantages, typically through political lobbying." https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/special_interest

Comment: @wordsalad That's the compound or strong-collocation usage. Of course 'I have a special interest in Chinese pottery' may be used. Can you find 'yellow car' in the dictionary? Does that mean you shouldn't use it?

Comment: 'I have an/[a special] interest in' is a fixed form, and fixed expressions often resist modification. However, 'I have [special] interests in A, B and C' seems common enough on the internet. Be aware that the existence of the other, more restricted sense of 'special interest' that wordsalad mentions may lead to loss of clarity

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for giving a warning. "Loss of clarity" is exactly what I should have said.

Answer (score -1):

i would say,

I am especially interested in learning languages, computer programming, astronomy & economics.

Comment: I don't believe OP was asking for rewrites (though like you and the next answerer, I'd use one).

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You could say:

My particular areas of interest are language, computer programming, astronomy and economy.

Comment: I don't believe OP was asking for rewrites (though like you and the previous answerer, I'd use one).

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You could also put it this way. Also, using "a special interest" will be fine...

I have a special interest in learning languages, computer programming, astronomy and economy.

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: The above answers have modified the sentence a bit. This might be to give some clarity. But it certainly doesn't mean the line by @januaryananda cannot be used as it is by making changes to it (if any are needed). That's exactly what I've done.. But someone has edited the question now...so both my answer and the sentence in the question now is same...:) 

But as I mentioned,"a special interest" can be used because you are stressing more or telling specifically about that special interest that you have in something. Moreover, just using "special interest" just sounds a bit 'off' frankly..:)

Comment: The question having been edited now, there isn't a need to make any corrections to it I feel...
@David What do you think...

Comment: OP asks whether the indefinite article is appropriate. You just claim that it's not wrong to use it, without saying whether it's necessary, without explaining why the article is or is not needed, and without providing any supporting evidence. I almost always downvote such answers for people with 1000+ rep.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Indefinite articles are used for nouns basically. And the word 'special' can be used both as a noun and an adjective. So it justifies the use of "a special interest" over just "special interest"

Moreover indefinite articles are also used when adjectives are used. For eg. "They always made a special effort at Christmas". Here special is used as an adjective. So in both cases, the use "a special interest" can be justified.

Comment: No; article usage is in many areas highly idiosyncratic. Collins Cobuild have a 100+ page monograph on the subject, and it's not comprehensive. // There has been a thread on ELU trying to explain why 'a blinding light filled the valley' is acceptable, but 'a blinding sunlight filled the valley' has to be rendered 'blinding sunlight filled the valley'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes! which means their usage can vary from one case to the other. So on the basis of the explanation and the formal definition that 'indefinite articles are used before nouns', what is your opinion on this very ubiquitous usage of "a special interest"...?

Comment: That's hardly a well-defining 'definition'. // I've already commented above.

Comment: Ok..! Agreed to the lack of a precise definition in this case. But all of us know how frequently the format "a special interest" is used. And we do have some reasons to back this. But what are the reasons to not back the usage "a special interest" and go with just "special interest"?

Comment: The remarks I made apply generally and also in this case regardless of the question. You tell the poster that something will be fine. Without anything further you are asking him and anyone else interested in the question to trust your authority. You may well be correct and regard your answer as obvious. But how does he or we know you are correct? If the answer is so obvious to an English native speaker the question is best left unanswered and the poster directed to English Language Learners. See the [Help](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on this point.

Comment: @David I did provide an explanation above regarding the usage of "a" in the comments above. It in fact isn't my explanation but rather the explanation to which people stick and which causes them to use the indefinite article "a". Even I stick to this usage. But I'd be grateful if you can suggest an explanation to not use "a special interest" and rather resort to just "special interest". This will also help me to correct myself...:)

Comment: @D.M Whatever's your explanation or definition, it needs to be in your answer, not in the comments.

Comment: Whether definite or otherwise, all articles are a kind of [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Combinations_of_determiners), and determiners occupy [a prescribed slot](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874) in a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase#Components_of_noun_phrases), a position falling before any adjectives. So it doesn't matter that *special* can ever be a noun (as in *an interesting special*), because it sure isn’t one here. It’s just an adjective (as *new* would be in *a new interest*), not an attributive noun modifying *interest*.